# How to ignore whitespace in a file for c++

Tags: c++, file, io, whitespace, istream

I'm a beginner to c++ and one of my homework assignments is to add two binary numbers located in a file. These numbers are separated by a space within the file. Assuming all binary numbers are 8-bits. So we read them from a file and store the 8-bits into a variable called byte that is a member each Byte object.

Ex)

10111010 11110000

11111111 00000000

Is this the correct way to write the coding for ignoring the white spaces?

```
int Byte::read(istream & file){
    file.skipws;
    file.get(byte, 8);
}
```

Or is this a better way?

```
int Byte::read(istream & file){
file.getline(byte, 8, ' ');
}
```

Thanks for any help. Apologizes if this was answered somewhere else. All I could find was examples that didn't involve files.

Comment: Your code is missing `return` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skipping whitespace is enabled by default for text streams.

```
std::string num1, num2;
if (file >> num1 >> num2)
{
   // use them
}
```

Since, apparently, you cannot use std::string:

```
#include <fstream>

std::istream& read8(std::istream& ifs, char(&arr)[8])
{
    return ifs >> arr[0] >> arr[1] >> arr[2] >> arr[3] >> arr[4] >> arr[5] >> arr[6] >> arr[7];
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("input.txt");

    char a[8], b[8];
    while (read8(file, a) && read8(file, b))
    {
        // add a and b
    }

}
```

Comment: updated in case you can't uhse `std::string` (why don't you tell us?)